# Symfony2 cache permissions issue ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, permissions, xampp

i have install lampp 1.8.1 in /opt/lampp.Everything is working fine.

i added my current user as owner to the htdocs folder so that i can write to htdocs folder.

then i created my symfony2 project. everything worked fine and i was able to run the configuration page properly.

but when i cleared the cache using command

```
sudo php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
sudo php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

the cache gets cleared but then there is permissions issue. when i try to access the same configuration page as before it gives me an error in browser:

> " RuntimeException: Failed to write cache file
>   "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php"."

but then when i change the permissions of the cache folder again using :

```
sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache
```

the page is again displayed properly

I dont want to change permissions everytime after clearing the cache.
Is there a solution or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What are the app/cache permissions and ownership `ls -l app/cache` after you clear the cache?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See "Setting up Permissions" in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup.
My preferred way in Ubuntu is setfacl, it works (just need to install a package first time):

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

Comment: Do `sudo apt-get install acl` if there is no command setfacl on your host

Answer (score 0):

if user don't have root privileges correct is

```
su root 
export user="changeToYouUsername"

setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:$user:rwX var/cache var/log
setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:$user:rwx var/cache var/log
```

this example

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

work only if current user have root and this is web log user (if we do it from root account - persmissions fail - it use $whoami as user name

this is sudo user for symfony 4

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var/cache var/log;
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx var/cache var/log;
```

Answer (score 0):

With symfony3

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var/cache var/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx var/cache var/logs
```

works for me.

Comment: I doubt that the commands will help in the specific case, but this may point in the right direction.